# How to use PartialAsync() twice and still get input from either one of the Partial Async renders

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I am using a `MainLogin.cshtml` component to choose whether to load up the Register or Login page, based off of whether there are or aren't users in the Database.

However, instead of creating a user when I register, the website throws an error, saying that Input is null (i.e Input.Password)

Here is `MainLogin.cshtml`:

```
@model Path.To.MainLoginModel

@{
}

@if (Model.ShowRegister)
{
    @await Html.PartialAsync("Path/To/Register.cshtml", Model.registerModel);
}
else{
    @await Html.PartialAsync("Path/To/Login.cshtml", Model.loginModel);

}
```

And here is the code behind it, `MainLogin.cshtml.cs`:

```
public class MainLoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IMediator mediator;
        public readonly RegisterModel registerModel;
        public readonly LoginModel loginModel;
        public MainLoginModel(IMediator mediator, RegisterModel registerModel, LoginModel loginModel)
        {
            this.mediator = mediator;
            this.registerModel = registerModel;
            this.loginModel = loginModel;
        }
        public bool ShowRegister { get; set; }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            ShowRegister = (await mediator.Send(new CheckUsers())).UsersDontExist;
            return Page();
        }

        public async Task OnPostAsync()
        {
            ShowRegister = (await mediator.Send(new CheckUsers())).UsersDontExist;
            if (ShowRegister)
            {
                await registerModel.OnPostAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                await loginModel.OnPostAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

Both `RegisterModel` and `LoginModel` have the `InputModel` class defined inside them:

```
public class InputModel
        {
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        }
```

The Login and Register pages both worked fine until I tried to make them share space on one page, which makes me think that `PartialAsync()` is to blame, but I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-7.0) related:

> A partial view is a Razor markup file (.cshtml) without a @page
> directive that renders HTML output within another markup file's
> rendered output.

In another words,it's Razor View instead of Razor Page, doesn't have handler(onGet,OnPost...)

So,If you want to share same content between Register Page and Login Page
You should create a partial View or work with another Layout Page for the two razor page above,not treate the two Pages as partial view

In your Login/Register Page:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("SharedContent.cshtml", sharedModel);
```

add a Razor View(Notice not Razor Page) `SharedContent.cshtml`

Check in the handler of Login Page:

```
public IActionResut YourHandler ()
{

    If(!user.exists)
    {
      return RedirecttoPage("Register")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, though my intent wasn't to have shared content between pages. It still helps to know that PartialAsync returns a view, not a page, so again, thank you kindly.